# Including a Ruby class from a separate file

Tags: ruby, class, module

For a while I had been including an entire class inside of a Ruby module. Apparently this is not what I am supposed to do. It appears that the point of a module is to store functions which can then be included as methods in a new class.

I don't want this. I have a class that I want to keep in a separate file which I can access from other files. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This post clarifies the require_relative expression in case you are running into problems with the above example when on Ruby >=1.9.2
[Ruby require_relative example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Modules serve a dual purpose as a holder for functions and as a namespace.  Keeping classes in modules is perfectly acceptable.  To put a class in a separate file, just define the class as usual and then in the file where you wish to use the class, simply put `require 'name_of_file_with_class'` at the top.  For instance, if I defined class `Foo` in `foo.rb`, in `bar.rb` I would have the line `require 'foo'`.

If you are using Rails, this include often happens automagically

Edit: clarification of file layout

```
#file: foo.rb
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

...

```
#file: bar.rb
require 'foo'

Foo.new
```

If you are in Rails, put these classes in `lib/` and use the naming convention for the files of lowercase underscored version of the class name, e.g. `Foo` -> `foo.rb`, `FooBar` -> `foo_bar.rb`, etc.

As of ruby version 1.9 you can use `require_relative`, to require files relatively to the file you are editing.

Comment: thanks, very helpful. could you clarify that last sentence? it seems you may have had a typo(?).

If class foo is stored in bar.rb, i require 'foo' in bazcontroller.rb?
Then foo.new is usable in bazcontroller.rb?

Comment: Maybe it would be nice to add some info on 'require_relative' for Ruby 1.9 since the code doesn't work for this version.

Comment: @boutta Thank you for the 1.9 clarification, this fixed my issue.

Comment: Answer saved the say for me. I had a class "SendGridHelper" in a file called "app/lib/sendgrid_helper.rb" I had to change the file name to "app/lib/send_grid_helper.rb".

Answer (score 2):

You can also use load. Also you use require relative if the file is in the same directory.  Read this link for further understanding: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html

Comment: Thanks, everyone wants to require classes, but I simply had some secret keys that I wanted to keep out of github. A simple `load secrets.rb` fits the bill perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

When Using Require, inside the string indicate the full path name of the class you are refereing to unless its in the Root Folder of Ruby

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApp
|_ app
|_ bin
|_ etc, etc
root_level_file.rb
```

You can just do:
`require './root_level_file'`.

`RootLevelFile.new`