# instantiate Foo with ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, require, instantiation

How do I [instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050749/262852) Foo from `bar.rb`?

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

```
# bar.rb
require 'foo'

Foo.new
```

```
$ ruby bar.rb 
/home/thufir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- foo (LoadError)
    from /home/thufir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from bar.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Not using modules at the moment.  Works fine when `Foo` is declared inside the same script:

```
# bar.rb with Foo declared inside
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "foo"
  end
end

Foo.new
```

```
$ ruby bar.rb 
foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace is telling you that your `require 'foo'` is not working because it can't find the file `foo.rb`.

That is because `require` interprets the argument you give it as an absolute path, or it searches your ruby load path for the specified file.

You could resolve this by providing an absolute path to the file. In this case: `require '/home/thufir/hello/foo'` will work for you.

You could also use `require_relative 'foo'`, which will search for a file `foo.rb` in the same directory as your `bar.rb`.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require